# Need to create a single page of labels in SSRS all with the same data

Tags: reporting-services

I'm trying to create a label report in SSRS (yeah yeah I know, old school.  Moving to 2014 shortly but need this report now) where all the labels contain the same data.  Basically the user picks a single person from a list and prints a whole page of labels for that person.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Selecting a single record and then getting a 3 column label report to reproduce the record result in all 30 labels on the page.  It can be done in Access but I can't seem to figure out how to make SSRS do it.

Comment: It can be done but it's not straight forward so the easiest way is to simply create arectangle big enough for one label, put all the label controls inside that rectangle and then  copy/paste it as many times as you need in the design to full your page.

Comment: Ouch..... Ok.  Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this.

1. There is a multi-column property on the report body. It is in the columns[] property. You can select 1...n columns. This will duplicate your label x number of times across the page.
2. Add a table to the report and create X number of columns. In each column place a rectangle with your label fields.

In both cases your should bind your report to a dataset that returns the targeted user's label data repeated for however many number of times you need the repeaters to repeat.